# Internal Salesforce.com Error in a trigger when upserting Records

Tags: trigger

Actually i was trying to understand flow, that's why i have create this trigger. I have created a CSV with 4 Records having 2 existing Records (which have another field changed value), 2 new record. When I upsert this CSV I  get an error ***Internal Salesforce.com Error*** and a mail from support@salesforce.com that **"Please contact salesforce.com Customer Support "**

It would be helpful if anyone can tell me output of trigger when upserting this CSV.

[image]

```
 trigger check on faculty__c (after update, after insert) {

        system.debug('This is Trigger.new size '+trigger.new.size());
        system.debug(trigger.new);                        

        if(trigger.isUpdate){

            system.debug('This is after update trigger.new' + trigger.new.size());
            system.debug(trigger.new);
            system.debug('This is after update trigger.old' +trigger.old.size());
            system.debug(trigger.old);

        }

        if(trigger.isInsert){

            system.debug('This is after insert ' +trigger.new.size());
            system.debug(trigger.new);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the code in this trigger. At this point, it could execute in a Before context and not just in an After context.

```
trigger check on faculty__c (after update, after insert) {

        system.debug('This is Trigger.new size '+trigger.new.size());
        // system.debug(trigger.new);
        // the above line won't return anything

    if(trigger.isAfter){

        if(trigger.isInsert){

            system.debug('This is after insert ' +trigger.new.size());
            // system.debug(trigger.new);
            // the above line won't return anything
        }

        if(trigger.isUpdate){

            system.debug('This is after update trigger.new' + trigger.new.size());
            // system.debug(trigger.new);
            // the above line won't return anything
            system.debug('This is after update trigger.old' +trigger.old.size());
            // system.debug(trigger.old);
            // the above line won't return anything

        }

    }

}
```

I also have a preference and it's something of a convention to put insert code before update code, so you'll notice that I've re-ordered the sequence. The same applies to putting Before code in ahead of After code.

Once you do this, your debug log should give you the following:

```
This is Trigger.new size 4
This is after insert 2
This is after update trigger.new2
This is after update trigger.old ?? 
Not certain what this would be, have never checked, could depend on size of existing records or size of trigger.new. 
Try it and find out. It's not really important.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, in this trigger we already specify event (after update, after insert) than why again you write  if(trigger.isAfter) body, and i have try many time but i am facing same error, is their any reason for this error.

Comment: I recognize you've specified it in your definition, but that's the conventional coding method. I suspect your error has more to do with your data upsert failing for something related to your external Id relationship; particularly since the message says to contact customer support. It also could be a base level issue with your SF instance's database or even something peculiar with your CSV file (doubt the latter). Only they would know.

Comment: Hello crmprogdev, i got the output using upserting set of records from Anonymous widow, output as follows:<br/>--------
 This is Trigger.new size 2-------This is after insert 2--------Trigger.new size 3--------This is after update trigger.new 3---------This is after update trigger.old 3

Comment: In after_update body "trigger.old" also contain first records which doesn't have any updated value.

Comment: Was in a hurry and didn't think about the fact it would execute twice, once for after insert and once for after update. The 3 would be because of the additional updated record with no changes and that makes sense to me. It appears trigger.old only references the records in trigger.new. That's good to know. Thanks for reporting back.